# C# VSTO - dynamically set RibbonControl

Tags: c#, combobox, vsto, ribbon-control

I have a customized Ribbon in Word. The Ribbon has one comboBox: **comboBox_recentConditions** which was defined using the Designer - so it's initalized and is empty at load. Now, I would like to dynamically set this comboBox each time the Application_WindowActivate event is fired.

Each Word document has its own instance of class called **RibbonControls**:

```
class RibbonControls
{
    private RibbonComboBox recentConditionComboBox;

    public RibbonControls()
    {
        this.recentConditionComboBox = new RibbonComboBox();
    }

    public RibbonComboBox RecentConditionComboBox
    {
        get
        {
            return recentConditionComboBox;
        }
        set
        {
            recentConditionComboBox = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Now in Application_WindowActivate event i do the following:

```
    static void Application_WindowActivate(Document doc, Window Wn)
    {
        Globals.Ribbons.SourceRibbon.comboBox_recentConditions = WordGate.docRibbonControls.RecentConditionComboBox; 
    }
```

**The problem** is that the Ribbon comboBox control doesn't changes, it's always empty, even after Application_WindowActivate is called.
I tested at run-time to see if each document indeed has its own comboBox with its items - which seems to work.
What am I missing?

**To clear my question:**
Let's say I have 3 items in the comboBox.Items. When clicking on it I see nothing, but if I add this:

```
MessageBox.Show(Globals.Ribbons.SourceRibbon.comboBox_recentConditions.Items.Count.ToString());
```

at the end of `Application_WindowActivate` it will print the number 3.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You cant do it that way. Please have a read on [Ribbon callbacks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee691833.aspx)

You have to use the getItemLabel event which will add items to combo box. If you want to load the combobox during WindowActivate then call [Ribbon.Invalidate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.core.iribbonui.invalidate%28v=office.14%29.aspx) or [Ribbon.InvalidateControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.core.iribbonui.invalidatecontrol%28v=office.14%29.aspx) which will call all relevant ribbon callbacks.

Comment: I tried: 
Globals.Ribbons.SourceRibbon.RibbonUI.InvalidateControl("comboBox_recentConditions");
Globals.Ribbons.SourceRibbon.RibbonUI.Invalidate();

But it doesn't work.

Comment: It should be Globals.ThisAddin.Ribbon.Invalidate()

Comment: Ribbon does not exist in ThisAddIn

Comment: Sorry it should be your Ribbon class name based on your code above it is RibbonControls

Comment: @Kiru: Calling myRibbon.RibbonUI.Invalidate(); does NOT work for me. Any guess?

Comment: @Kiru: Neither InvalidateControl(myButtonId) does... :-(